# minimized probability of a coin toss

Tags: probability

> A fair coin is tossed $n$ times and heads shows $k$ times. Find the smallest number $n$ such that $P(0.49≤k/n≤0.51) > 0.95$.

So I have no idea where to go with this, my first idea was to use $\binom{n}{k}p^{k}q^{n-k}$ but if I am understanding the given notation correctly, the number of coin tosses is less than 1?

Comment: Coin tosses must be an integer. You cannot "half-toss" a coin. It makes no sense.

Comment: I think he's saying that the ratio $\frac{k}{n}$ lies between those two values.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the smallest $n$ such that this probability, which is 
$$
 \sum_{0.49 n \leq k < 0.51 n} 2^{-n}\binom{n}{k} > \frac{19}{20}
$$
With a fair coin you yyous $p=q=\frac12$.

You are probably meant to then use the normal approximation to the binomial coefficient
$$
\log\binom{n}{k} \approx k\log(\frac{n}{k} + \frac12) + k - \frac12 \log (2\pi k)
$$ and use $k = \frac{n}2$ and assume the binomial coefficient varies slowly in the area of interest; that would give a minimal $n$ near $9500$.

The actual answer is $n = 9551$ at which the probability is $0.950547$.

Comment: I am not sure I follow, so the ration of number of tosses and number of heads stays in between 0.49 and 0.59, and the probability of this happening is larger than 0.95, the above equation must be solved for n, with k=n/2 plugged in. That simplifies to -0.5*log(n)+0.69897*n-0.248575, when I solve, I don't seem to get the same n value

Comment: You are right, if you assume no variation in the area of interest, you get $n=3546$.  So that is a miserable assumption.